# Intersection type of generic and 'any' does not narrow down properties

Tags: typescript

Why is it when doing an intersection of two types, one of which is any, I am unable to get TypeScript to guard against additional properties. It looks like the 'any' take precedence over the type that I have defined.

I have the code in a [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMAjAHgAoD4AUAHAQwCcCBbAZwC5EBvRAEwKgIH5qNEBfASloChEiCAnJwANgFMAdGLgBzfMTLkpjZtwDcfTnz6hIsBMgBMmXIRIVqdNa3ZdEAMloMmdxATABPLrxoChEXFpWQULZVU3TW1dVDQ6AmpyKCIYMDkuXBs3aw9qACJgODh8hx4tOISklLSMzizXZlzExABWMujKvMRk1PTMnGymlxbC4vyAGkQAIwKiko6tPVMqnpr%20%20sHGltX2zl8Kle7e2oGhne6xkqnZtsW%20IA)
I would have expected the code on line 14 to throw an error since `b` is not a property defined on `<P>`

```
function f1<P>(params: { data?: P }) {
  console.log(params.data);
}

function f2<P>(params: { data?: P } & { data?: any }) {
  console.log(params.data);
}

f1<{ a: string }>({ data: { a: "foo" } });
f1<{ a: string }>({ data: { a: 5 } });
f1<{ a: string }>({ data: { a: "foo", b: "foo" } });

f2<{ a: string }>({ data: { a: 5 } });
f2<{ a: string }>({ data: { a: "foo", b: 5 } });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{ data?: P } & { data?: any }` becomes `{ data?: P & any }` and therefor `data` becomes `any`

just dont use `any`, use `unknown` for unknown typings and then type narrowings to use the props